# Docker error at startup : System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: docker, installation, wsl-2, docker-desktop

## Context

I'm on Windows 10 Entreprise, version 1909 (18363.1801) and I've done all available updates before next steps.

I've tried to install Docker Desktop 4.0.1 following [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/). I've enabled WSL2 feature, I've installed the linux kernel update package, then I've installed Docker Desktop, following instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/) without any error.

## My problem

When I try to start Docker Desktop, I accept the terms, then an error occurs :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to set version to docker-desktop: exit code: -1
stdout: Paramètres de console non pris en charge. Pour pouvoir utiliser cette fonctionnalité, la console héritée doit être désactivée.
```

Full stacktrace [here](https://pastebin.com/j6gps5Lx)

Did I've missed something during installation ? What should I do to be able to use Docker Desktop ?

I've tried to uninstall then install again Docker Desktop, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Would this help? https://fluka.cern/documentation/installation/fluka-flair-windows10-wsl#:~:text=1.1.4.&text=Unsupported%20console%20settings.,Console%20option%2C%20and%20click%20OK.

Comment: Thanks for the link @NoamYizraeli, are you talking about the "Enable Windows Subsystem for Linux" part ? I've tried to run that command, but it doesn't change anything after restarted Docker Desktop, I've always the same error. I've just saw that you linked to the "Legacy console error" part, but I don't understand what should I do with these informations

Comment: Legacy console looks like a windows feature (there's also *new console*)

Comment: Try this tutorial to disable legacy console https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/94146-enable-disable-legacy-console-mode-all-consoles-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Glad to here, I'll encapsulate it in an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP had the lagacy console enabled creating a known issue with wsl backend. After disabling it using [this link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/94146-enable-disable-legacy-console-mode-all-consoles-windows-10-a.html) the issue was resolved

Answer (score 1):

As [Noam Yizraeli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459640/noam-yizraeli) suggested, disable legacy console worked for me ([tutorial here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/94146-enable-disable-legacy-console-mode-all-consoles-windows-10-a.html)).

I've disabled legacy console on PowerShell Console and restarted Docker, then everything's working now.

I've followed these steps:

1. Close Docker Desktop
2. Open a PowerShell
3. Right click or press and hold on the title bar of the console
   window, and click/tap on Properties
4. Click/tap on the Options tab, uncheck the Use legacy console box and
   click/tap on OK to apply
5. Start Docker Desktop

Thanks again to [Noam Yizraeli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459640/noam-yizraeli).